# Weird typecasting behaviour in unistd.h read()

Tags: c, binary

Consider the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *buf[100] = {0};
    __int32_t buflen = 0x80000000;
    size_t len = read(0, buf, buflen);
    printf("%d", len);
}
```

When compiling this with gcc 12.2.0 I get the warning messages:

```
<snip>
foo.c:8:18: warning: ‘read’ specified size 18446744071562067968 exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
    8 |     size_t len = read(0, buf, buflen);
<snip>
```

and read returns `-1` i.e. an error at runtime.

What I don't understand about this:
I build the lowest (?) signed int32. Then this signed i32 gets passed to `read(..., ..., size_t buflen)`, where `size_t`is an unsigned integer. Thus read should "interpret" `buflen` as a zero-padded `size_t` i.e. `0x00_00_00_00_80_00_00_00` which is exactly what happens when I manually cast `buflen`  to `size_t`.

Why does it exeed the buffer size then and where does the 18446744071562067968 (something close to the max value of `size_t`) come from?

A bit of context:

- Yes I am quite aware that this will overflow the buffer.
- This is supposed to be bad code that might get exploited.

I tried several values for `buflen` with sometimes inconsistent behavior. I assume this is some u.b.. I expect read to interpret the passed parameter as `0x80000000`

Edit: `buflen` gets extended to `0xFFFFFFFF80000000`. But why?

Comment: This is completely besides the point, but that `char *buf[100]` is really weird here, it should be `char buf[100]`, right?

Comment: Yes you are probably right. I don't really code in C. This is a recreation of some decompiled binary I got in a CTF.

Comment: "... which is exactly what happens when I manually cast buflen to size_t." ahhh.... I like to see that ;-)

Comment: OT: Printing a `size_t` variable using `%d` is bad. Actually the retun type of `read` isn't `size_t` but `ssize_t`.

Comment: It's really strange that `__int32_t buflen = 0x80000000;` doesn't produce a warning on neither gcc nor clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` function expects a `size_t` type for the last parameter (i.e. your `buflen`). However, you give it an object of type `int32_t`. So there will be a conversion from `int32_t` to `size_t`.

For such conversions the C standard says:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, **if
> the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged**.

So the question is: Can your value of `buflen` be represented in an object of type `size_t`?

You assigned the value `0x80000000` so let's check what that is:

```
int32_t buflen = 0x80000000;
printf("%" PRId32 "\n", buflen);
```

Output:

```
-2147483648
```

oh... a negative value... Since `size_t` can't represent negative values the rule above doesn't apply in your case. We need another rule from the standard. It goes:

> Otherwise, **if the new type is unsigned**, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.

With the note that:

> The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression

As `size_t` is unsigned this rule applies. So let's find the maximum for `size_t`

```
printf("%zu\n", SIZE_MAX);
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615
```

So according to the standard we need to do:

```
           -2147483648
+ 18446744073709551615
+                    1
  --------------------
  18446744071562067968
  ====================
```

The value 18446744071562067968 can be represented in a `size_t` object so that will be the value passed to `read`

BTW:

Here

```
printf("%d", len);
```

you print a `size_t` object using `%d`. That is wrong (undefined behavior). Use `%zu` for `size_t`

That said... the return value from `read` is not a `size_t` but a `ssize_t` so the type is wrong from the start.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

Your `size_t` is 64 bits long. `(int32_t)0x80000000 == -2147483648`. When you convert this negative value to 64 bit version it is getting signed extended. 64 bit version of `-2147483648` is `0xffffffff80000000`.

It shows how important is to use the correct types. Instead `int32_t` use the correct `size_t` type.

Do noy use internal `__intxx_t` types. Use standard (defined in `stdint.h`) `intxx_t` types

Side notes:

1. `char *buf[100]` defined an array of 100 pointers to `char`. I do not think that it is exactly what you want.
2. You pass much smaller buffer than the max read size. It invokes undefined behaviour